# Cannot pass Context when building a GridView in Kotlin

Tags: android, gridview, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I'm looking for some help creating a GridView in Kotlin. Please do not show me JAVA code as I have tried adapting various JAVA examples already.

So, I created the extension to BaseAdapter, but I cannot get to pass the context. The Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#example) shows how it accesses by calling `gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));`.

**Assigning the BaseAdapter to a GridView element in my activity**

```
collectionView.adapter = ButtonAdapter()
```

**I have tried passing the context inside but I get error for too many parameters**

```
collectionView.adapter = ButtonAdapter(baseContext())
```

**My BaseAdapter extension with the method I try to initialise it by**

```
class ButtonAdapter : BaseAdapter() {
       var con: Context? = null
           //.....
       fun ButtonAdapter(context: Context) {
           con = context
       }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in trying to pass the context and create the GridView? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your class like this:

```
class ButtonAdapter(val context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {
 // ...
```

And then you can pass context:

```
ButtonAdapter(context)
```

`fun` is used for functions. To pass data through constructor, you can change your code like above which is the primary constructor.

Adding `val` is optional. It makes the `context` a property of the class so that you can access the `context` in the class.

Comment: Wow, that was so obvious, it's embarrassing. Will accept as answer once the 10 minutes have passed. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help :) Everyone does mistakes. I'd suggest reading the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) also.

Comment: Saw that document few times while searching but it just didn't sink in :)

Comment: Thank you ! I forgot to put val and I was looking for the mistake !!! People like you saved me from hours of stress !

Answer (score 2):

You can send it in the primary constructors, like this below.

```
public class ButtonAdapter(context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {

    private val mInflator: LayoutInflater

    init {
        this.mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

###Here are the Instructions

//You will change it to accept context

```
class ClassName(val mcontext: Context):
```

//In Activity pass the context

```
ClassName(this).methodCall()
```